# How to continue script if authentication pop up doesn't load or credentials entered are not correct?

Tags: automation, autoit

I am automating a web page using Selenium for which I am getting a Windows authentication pop-up. Since Selenium can't handle this I am using AutoIt. It is working fine but :

1. If I minimize the popup AutoIt will not find it. How to come out of AutoIt when it doesn't?
2. When I am using `WinExists()` it is not entering userid and password and gets stuck on the popup window. The code does enter credentials when I remove the `Winexists()` function.

```
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:Intermediate D3D Window; INSTANCE:1]", "", "10")

If WinExists("[CLASS:Intermediate D3D Window; INSTANCE:1]") Then

    Send("userid")
    Send("{TAB}")
    Send("password")
    Send("{ENTER}")

EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sTitle = "[CLASS:Intermediate D3D Window]"

If WinWait($sTitle, "", 10) Then

    If SendKeepActive($sTitle) Then
        Send("userid")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("password")
        Send("{ENTER}")
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Different options exist to restore a window. `SendKeepActive` is probably a good choice if working with `Send` as it tries to keep the window active for each call of `Send`. To continue the code, just add more code after the last `EndIf`. I have the removed the `INSTANCE:1` for the window title as titles have no instance property that I know and it seems to be ignored in my testing. Adjust the title as needed.

Below is example code using different options. I tested with this on Firefox with this page loaded and displayed. Change the title if needed. The `Send('{ALT}')` should be safe as a `Send` test as it will just display the menu bar. The messages of events to written to console so as not to interrupt the automation.

```
ConsoleWrite('Start' & @CRLF)

$sTitle = 'automation - How to continue script'

If WinWait($sTitle, '', 10) Then

    _WinMin($sTitle)

    ; Option 1. SendKeepActive restores the window and tries to keep it active for each Send.
    If SendKeepActive($sTitle) Then
        ConsoleWrite('SendKeepActive' & @CRLF)
        Send('{ALT}')
    EndIf

    _WinMin($sTitle)

    ; Option 2. WinActivate restores once.
    If WinActivate($sTitle) Then
        ConsoleWrite('WinActivate' & @CRLF)
    EndIf

    _WinMin($sTitle)

    ; Option 3. WinSetState can restore and WinActivate makes the window active.
    If WinSetState($sTitle, '', @SW_RESTORE) Then
        ConsoleWrite('@SW_RESTORE')

        Sleep(1000)

        If WinActivate($sTitle) Then
            ConsoleWrite('...WinActivate')
        EndIf

        ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
    EndIf

    _WinMin($sTitle)
EndIf

ConsoleWrite('Done' & @CRLF)


Func _WinMin($sTitle, $iSleep = 3000)
    ; Minimize window for testing.
    Sleep($iSleep)
    WinSetState($sTitle, '', @SW_MINIMIZE)
    Sleep($iSleep)
EndFunc
```

So you have other options if the initial code does not work well.

References:

- [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)
- [SendKeepActive](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/SendKeepActive.htm)
- [WinActivate](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm)
- [WinSetState](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm)
- [WinWait](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm)